# Running cron job in Java

Tags: java, triggers, cron, jobs

This is my `ScheduleFactory` Class which creates and schedule the Job for me.

I want to understand how this Java class will be called to trigger the cron job.

```
public class XScedulerFacory 
{
    public void jobSchedule() throws SchedulerException
    {  
        SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        JobDetail job = newJob(MyJob.class).withIdentity("job", "group1")
                                           .build();
        Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                                      .startNow()
                                      .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                                      .withIntervalInSeconds(40)
                                      .repeatForever())
                                      .build();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

This is my job class where i will have th execute method

```
public class MyJob implements org.quartz.Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("MyJob.execute()");
    }
```

I want to understand how can i call `XScedulerFacory.jobSchedule()` method. I wanted to run this independently and trigger my job every 40 secs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
package poop.test;

public class MainTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        XScedulerFacory factory = new XScedulerFacory();
        try
        {
            factory.jobSchedule();    
        }
        catch(SchedulerException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a main class. I wanted to run this class all the time so that it polls the db